# Adodb connection to an acces database with an https adres

Tags: http, adodb

I'm trying to open an acces database that is stored in sharepoint

I have an HTTP adres to it
I try to connect it with the following code

```
    cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.connectionstring = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=Verzamelstaat.mdb;DefaultDir=https://share-intra.philips.com/sites/STS20150715103003/Shared Documents/Pilot Verzamelstaat;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;"
```

cn.open()

But it keeps failing

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open MDB file. "MDB file" is not the same as "MS SQL Connection:. HTTP is not SMB like.

Answer: Because HTTP Server will not permit you to change file on remote server.